# Process with subprocess module never stops running

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I've just started using the subprocess module on Python 3 and I can't figure out exactly how it works.
This is a function I wrote to power the USB ports on and off. It works, but then it runs indefinitely and I can't do anything else until forcing it to stop with Ctrl+C. The print statements also never get called:

```
def usb_power_toggle(s):
    power_off, power_on = "echo '1-1' |sudo tee sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind", "echo '1-1' |sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind"
    if s == "off":
        subprocess.run(power_off, shell = True)
        print("USB power off!")
    elif s == "on":
        subprocess.run(power_on, shell = True)
        print("USB power on!")
    else:
        raise ValueError
```

Does anyone understand what the problem is? Could you please tell me how to close the process after it does what it's supposed to?

Comment: I couldn't duplicate. I just used a simple command - `"echo 'off'"` and `"echo 'on'"` - everything else in the function the same; and it worked so something must be *hanging* in the command you are trying to run.

Comment: Set the subprocess' [`daemon`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.daemon) flag to `True` to allow the main process to exit even if it's still running.

Comment: @martineau ?? `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'daemon'`

Comment: You'll need to explicitly create a [`Process`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) instance to set it. Also note that the `daemon` keyword argument for `__init__()` wasn't added until version 3.3—so you'll need to set the attribute manually yourself after creation in earlier versions. I usually do it that way to be more backwards compatible.

Comment: @martineau - `subprocess` I think, not `multiprocessing.Process`

Comment: @wwii: I'm aware the OP is trying to use `subprocess`, however that module doesn't support `daemon` processes, so to do what I originally suggested would require them to switch to using `multiprocessing.Process` instead—which can do what's needed.

Comment: Thanks @martineau, but I couldn't get this to work. `multiprocessing.Process` can only do function calls (right?) and not run the system command line like I want to, and calling another function inside it didn't do any difference.

Comment: Seems like you could write a function that executed the command line...using [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) perhaps.

Comment: I tried that, with `os.system` and also `subprocess`, which is what I started with. Using multiprocessing didn't make any difference...

Answer (score 0):

just use popen

```
    def usb_power_toggle(s):
       from os import popen
       power_off, power_on = "echo '1-1' |sudo tee sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind", "echo '1-1' |sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind"
       if s == "off":
           popen(power_off)
           print("USB power off!")
       elif s == "on":
           popen(power_on)
           print("USB power on!")
       else:
           raise ValueErro
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. The process terminates but the USB isn't turned on/off; nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work after trying some different things.
I must admit that I don't understand why this worked, or why I had this problem before in the first place. If somebody knows that and is willing to clarify I'd be grateful.

```
from subprocess import STDOUT, check_output

def call_cmd(cmd):
    try:
        check_output(cmd, stderr=STDOUT, timeout=1, shell = True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        print("Exit status 1")

def usb_power_toggle(s):
    power_off, power_on = "echo '1-1' |sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind", \
    "echo '1-1' |sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind"
    if s == "off":
        call_cmd(power_off)
        print("USB power off")
    elif s == "on":
        call_cmd(power_on)
        print("USB power on")
    else:
        raise ValueError
```